# how to setup proper ACL to allow users from a domain only for CORS

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using cloud storage to serve many JSON files, for cross-origin resource sharing; but I found do I have to set ACL to allow ALL users readable ?

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

So far I figured out two ways to access these resources:

1. `https:// storage.googleapis.com /my-bucket/my-full-keyname.json`
2. `https:// storage.cloud.google.com /my-bucket/my-full-keyname.json` (cookie based, will redirect to `accounts.google.com` for authentication and redirect to xxx.googleusercontent.com/...? looks like a signed url; but the response doesn't have CORS header)

On the bucket I have setup proper CORS with allowing GET request from Origin: http:// www.softwareishard.com

http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/?path=https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/my-full-keyname.json

but the problem is I found the only way it can work is I setup all readable ACL; but some of the files are confidential I don't want world wide readable;

with 2nd kind of url access by `https:// storage.cloud.google.com / my-bucket/my-full-keyname.json` I can setup ACL like `gsutil acl ch -g my-domain.com:r gs://my-bucket/my-full-keyname.json` here my-domain.com is a hosted domain on Google Apps, so it works with restricted access to authenticated my-domain.com users only. But the problem with `https:// storage.cloud.google.com` is it doesn't support above CORS. Trying to  load `http:// www.softwareishard.com /har/viewer/?path=https:// storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/my-full-keyname.json` I can see 302 redirection in Network Panel in CORS request, it redirect to `accounts.google.com` for authentication, but har-viewer just failed to load.

the question is storage.googleapis.com can be accessed with CORS, but only when ACL set with All:Readable, all world wide anonymous readable;

with storage.cloud.google.com it's cookie based, can set ACL to be readable to only authenticated @my-domain.com users, not with world wide anonymous read; but this URL is a redirection to xxxx.googleusercontent.com/path/to/my-bucket/my-objkeyname?qk=some-long-signed-string and doesn't support CORS.

Is there any advice how to design ACL with CORS? thanks

Answer (score 0):

the question is storage.googleapis.com can be accessed with CORS, but only when ACL set with All:Readable, all world wide anonymous readable;

with storage.cloud.google.com it's cookie based, can set ACL to be readable to only authenticated @my-domain.com users, not with world wide anonymous read; but this URL is a redirection to xxxx.googleusercontent.com/path/to/my-bucket/my-objkeyname?qk=some-long-signed-string and doesn't support CORS.

Is there any advice how to design ACL with CORS? thanks